# Optimize EF core query in an alphabetically ordered list

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, entity-framework-core

I've been dealing with an issue lately, and although i have some solutions in mind, i'd like to find the best one from every point of view.

Let's say i have a WPF app with EF Core. There are about 3000 customers in my database (SQLite in my case, but in the future this should also work with slower ones). When the user opens the customer's list, i'm loading only some of them (quantity = 50, page = 0), in alphabetical order. As soon as the user scrolls down to the bottom, 50 more are loaded (quantity = 50, page = 1).

```
CustomerRepository.GetQueryableAll().Skip(page * quantity).Take(quantity).ToList();
```

Everything works fine. Here comes the problem though: there's a button to create a new customer, which opens a modal window. Let's say the user creates a customer with starting letter W. As soon as he/she hits SAVE, the new customer is saved to the database, the window is closed, and the list must be reloaded. But loading the whole list until W is, of course, really slow.

So far, i've tried to query the database in a background task and store how many customers start with each letter of the database in a static Dictionary: as soon as SAVE is hit, i can guess more or less how many "pages" to Skip() in the database and get the group of 50 in which the new customer will be. It works, it's quite fast, but i'm worried that it won't work in countries with non Latin alphabets:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<char, int>> GetCustomersByInitialsCount()
{
    return await Task.Run(async delegate
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
        {
            var count = await CustomerRepository.GetCustomerCountStartingWith(c.ToString());
            dictionary.Add(c, count);
        }
        return dictionary;
    });
}

[... and in the repository:]

public async Task<int> GetCustomerCountStartingWith(string startingLetter)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return await dbContext.Set<Customer>().CountAsync(p => p.LastName.ToUpper().StartsWith(startingLetter.ToUpper()));
    }
}
```

Otherwise, instead of this background query, i could also try to "guess" the right page depending on the starting char, but i'm still puzzled by the unexpected outcomes i could have with non latin languages.

If anybody knows better tools or have any other useful ideas, i'll gladly consider them!

Thank you very much in advance and happy coding.

Comment: What if you have both infinite paging and paging by pageIndex. After new user you just load list from current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add a request to get all the first "letters" in your table ?

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetCustomerFirstLetter()
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return await dbContext.Set<Customer>().Select(x => x.lastName.Substring(0, 1)).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

and then

```
public async Task<Dictionary<char, int>> GetCustomersByInitialsCount()
{
    return await Task.Run(async delegate
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        var letters = GetCustomerFirstLetter();
        foreach(letter in letters)
        {
            var count = await CustomerRepository.GetCustomerCountStartingWith(letter);
            dictionary.Add(letter, count);
        }
        return dictionary;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution**. *A little bit more efficient from my point of view*

Your problem boils down to how to get new customer's row number in whole dataset ordered by customer's name.

First of all, in plain `SQL` for SQLite or MSSQL you may solve your problem of getting right page number with  [ROW_NUMBER](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/) function. Query example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 rnd.rownum, rnd.LastName
  from (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY c.LastName) AS rownum, c.LastName
  FROM [Customer] c) rnd
WHERE rnd.LastName = '<your new customers name here>'
```

So, after getting exact rownumber value and having already page count param you can easily calculate needed page.

Getting back to your code. This feature can be implemented in EF with overloaded version of `Select` method, but unfortunately, it has not been implemented in EF Core for `IQueryable` yet ([see this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8263)).
But you can still pass exact query right to db using [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) method.

Solution consists of two steps:

1. To get required data you need to define `Query` for model builder this way (additional fields just for example, youl need `RowNum` only):

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Query<CustomerRownNum>();
   }

   public class CustomerRownNum
   {
       public long RowNum { get; set; }
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Then you need to pass mentioned above SQL query to context's Query method this way:

   ```
       string customerLastName = "<your customer's last name>";
       var result = dbContext.Query<CustomerRownNum>().FromSql(
           @"select top 1 rnd.RowNum, rnd.Id, rnd.LastName
               from 
               (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY c.LastName) AS RowNum
                   , c.Id, c.LastName
                 FROM [Customer] c) rnd
               WHERE rnd.LastName = {0}", customerLastName).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

Finally you'll get data you needed right in `result` variable.

Hope that helps!